After sending an authentication request to Spring Security, the same form is returned due to incorrect data, although the data is correct
Authentication is done by custom fields. But the type of one of the fields (pin) matches the field type that UserDetails requires, and the other field (phoneNumber) is of type Long, not String like username, and is used as Principal.
After entering the correct data in the fields and sending the authentication request, Spring re-submits the authentication form and throws an error "Invalid phone number or PIN". I suspect that it simply does not receive the Principal, but I am not sure and do not know why.
What could be the error, what did I do wrong and how to fix it?
Below are the codes that may be needed to solve the problem:
Spring Security configuration file:
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration {
    private final AuthProviderImpl authProvider;

    @Autowired
    public SecurityConfiguration(@Lazy AuthProviderImpl authProvider) {
        this.authProvider = authProvider;
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder =
                http.getSharedObject(AuthenticationManagerBuilder.class);
        authenticationManagerBuilder.authenticationProvider(authProvider);

        return authenticationManagerBuilder.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .requestMatchers("/BankAccounts/new").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/auth/login")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/auth/login")
                .permitAll();
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder getPasswordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(); 
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthProviderImpl authProvider(BankAccountsDetailService bankAccountsDetailService) {
        return new AuthProviderImpl(bankAccountsDetailService, getPasswordEncoder());
    }
}

Java class that implements UserDetails:
public class BankAccountDetails implements UserDetails {

    private final BankAccount bankAccount;
    private final Long phoneNumber;

    public BankAccountDetails(BankAccount bankAccount) {
        this.bankAccount = bankAccount;
        this.phoneNumber = bankAccount.getPhoneNumber();
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return List.of(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER")); 
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return this.bankAccount.getPin();
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return this.bankAccount.getFullName();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true; 
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true; 
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true; =
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return true; 
    }

    public Long getPhoneNumber() {
        return phoneNumber;
    }

    public BankAccount getBankAccount() {
        return this.bankAccount;
    }
}

Custom authentication provider:
@Component
public class AuthProviderImpl implements AuthenticationProvider {

    private final BankAccountsDetailService bankAccountsDetailService;
    private final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AuthProviderImpl.class);

    @Autowired
    public AuthProviderImpl(BankAccountsDetailService bankAccountsDetailService, PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder) {
        this.bankAccountsDetailService = bankAccountsDetailService;
        this.passwordEncoder = passwordEncoder;
    }

    @Override
    public PhoneNumberAuthToken authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        logger.info("authenticate method is called");

        Object principal = authentication.getPrincipal();
        if (principal == null) {
            logger.error("Principal is null");
            throw new BadCredentialsException("Principal is null");
        }

        String phoneNumberStr = principal.toString();
        logger.info("Received phone number: {}", phoneNumberStr);

        try {
            Long phoneNumber = Long.parseLong(phoneNumberStr);
            String pin = authentication.getCredentials().toString();
            logger.info("Phone number: {}", phoneNumber);
            logger.info("PIN: {}", pin);

            // load bank account details by phone number
            BankAccountDetails bankAccountDetails = (BankAccountDetails) bankAccountsDetailService.loadUserByPhoneNumber(phoneNumber);
            if (bankAccountDetails == null) {
                logger.error("Bank account not found for phone number: {}", phoneNumber);
                throw new BadCredentialsException("Неверный номер телефона или PIN-код");
            }

            // Checking PIN-code with PasswordEncoder
            if (!passwordEncoder.matches(pin, bankAccountDetails.getPassword())) {
                logger.error("PIN does not match for phone number: {}", phoneNumber);
                throw new BadCredentialsException("Incorrect Phone number or PIN-code");
            }

            logger.info("Authentication successful for phone number: {}", phoneNumber);
            return new PhoneNumberAuthToken(bankAccountDetails.getAuthorities(), phoneNumber, pin);

        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
logger.error("Invalid phone number format: {}", phoneNumberStr, e);
throw new BadCredentialsException("Invalid phone number format");
} catch (UsernameNotFoundException e) {
logger.error("User not found for phone number: {}", phoneNumberStr, e);
throw new BadCredentialsException("Invalid phone number or PIN");
} catch (Exception e) {
logger.error("Authentication error", e);
throw new BadCredentialsException("Authentication error");
       }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
        return PhoneNumberAuthToken.class.isAssignableFrom(authentication);
    }
}

Custom authentication token:
public class PhoneNumberAuthToken extends AbstractAuthenticationToken {

    private final Long phoneNumber;

    private final String pin;

    public PhoneNumberAuthToken(Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities, Long phoneNumber, String pin) {
        super(authorities);
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
        this.pin = pin;
        setAuthenticated(false);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getCredentials() {
        return pin;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getPrincipal() {
        return phoneNumber;
    }
}

Authentication form's body(if it can cause problems):
<body>
<div class="login-container">
    <h2 class="mt-5">Login form</h2>
    <form action="#" th:action="@{/auth/login}" method="post" class="mt-4">
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label for="phoneNumber" class="form-label">Phone number</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="phoneNumber" name="phoneNumber" required>
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label for="pin" class="form-label">PIN-код</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pin" name="pin" required>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Login </button>
    </form>

    <!-- Displaying authentication errors -->
    <div th:if="${param.error}" class="alert alert-danger mt-3">
        Incorrect phone number or PIN-code.
    </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.1.3/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</body>

I tried logging to find my error, but i don't know how to fix it.

there are several things wrong here and its quite clear that you are lacking a fundamental understanding of how spring security works. A principla is constructed AFTER a user has authenticated. Its the RESULT of a successful authentication. You in your AuthProviderImpl assume that it is something that you use to authenticate which is just faulty. Also spring has no idea what PhoneNumberAuthToken is, when you post to /auth/login springs default login endpoint will accept username and password as FORM parameters. And has no awareness of your custom parameters.

I suggest that you read up on the fundamental building blocks of spring security, how they work and how different parts are used https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authentication/architecture.html here, before deciding to directly write some kind of fully custom login.
